# Logback logging from java called from Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, logging, log4j, logback

I have some trace logging done in my Java classes wich I call from `Matlab`. I have `logback.xml` at the root of the JAR file I use from Matlab.

If I call these files from Java, logging works well, but if I call it from Matlab, no logging occur.

How to fix it?

Probably this is because `Matlab` is using `log4j` and it conflicts with `logback` somehow.

**UPDATE**

`logback.xml` file is follows:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUTMETHODNAME" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%method - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUTMETHODNAME" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

To call java method from Matlab I use [directives from the doumentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html). Particularly, I add JAR file to `Matlab`'s java path and then just refer method by it's `FQN`.

**UPDATE 2**

If I run from Java, my logger instance is of type:

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
```

If I run from Matlab my logger instance is of type:

```
org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter
```

This means I was right thinking about conflict. But to overcome this?

**UPDATE 3**

Adding `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j` to the distribution didn't help.

**UPDATE 4**

Removing of `<MATLAB>/java/jarext/slf4j` helped. Is there any softer method?

Comment: How are you calling it from MATLAB and how do you save the logs?

Comment: See my update please. I don't save the logs, I log to `STDOUT`.